# String or binary data truncated

Tags: sql-server, database

i am using microsoft sql server management and  I received an error called " String or binary data would be truncated."
 Before posting this question, I have read similar posts regarding this question. Many have said that the field is NOT big enough to hold the data.
However, I declared my "TrainerDesc" to have a varchar(3000) which is way bigger than the data inserted. So why do I still receive this error?

```
Create Table Trainer
(TrainerNo          char(8)      not null,          
 TrainerName        varchar(50)  not null,
 TrainerDesc        varchar(3000) null, 
 Primary Key (TrainerNo))
```

----------------------------------------------------Inserting Values----------------------------------------------------

```
Insert into Trainer
values
('T5690146', 'Mary Hoe', 'Mary Hoe is a qualified and highly experienced Yoga trainer who holds a yoga instructor certificate obtained from the yoga center singapore in 2002. Furthermore, she taught yoga in various community clubs for more than a decade including Pek Kio CC, Choa Chu Kang cc and Yew Tee cc.Mary loves to spread her knowledge and skills with people who are keen to learn more about Yoga.')
```

Comment: Tag your DBMS name and version. SQL Server, presumably, but it should be clearly tagged.

Comment: It works in both Mysql and Sql Server, I manage to create the table and the insert. What database do you use?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table? That DDL and Sample data won't cause that error on its own.

Comment: Stop using bad coding habits. Specify the list of columns you intend to  populate - otherwise you **MUST** provide the values to be inserted in the same order as the columns are defined in the table (which can change).

Comment: You could change varchar(3000) to TEXT

Comment: @russ NO!!! The TEXT datatype has been deprecated in favor of varchar(max) for more than a decade now. And changing the datatype to deal with an error is fixing the symptom, not the problem.

Comment: @SeanLange The problem is that there is no reason whatsoever that the given code generates the given error. Fixing the symptom is the only remaining alternative. TEXT works fine for me even if it is deprecated, how about varchar(max) itself instead of varchar(3000)?

Comment: TEXT is awful. You can't index it, you can't search it. You have to constantly convert it to a varchar so it is usable. But I strongly suspect there is a trigger in play here which is causing the problem.

Comment: @russ see here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql We do NOT want to use deprecated features, they can and will be removed at some point and then your code is broken. But to be fair, anything using the text datatype is already broken given the gyrations required to work with it.

Comment: The large value / object data type argument would appear to be ethical anyway more than finitely decided, if that's the question. The suggestion that developers shouldn't use object data types like TEXT makes all the sense in the world but not necessarily because it has been deprecated as that word means basically nothing except for the idea of second and SQL are both fiddle which I can't agree with at all.

Comment: That create/insert just worked on my SQL Server 13.0.4001. Which version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Mention your columns explicitly which is best practice

The simplest reason for the error is that your table definition has different column order to what you expect, which can happen if you added TrainerName afterwards or changed it by drop+add

```
Insert into Trainer (TrainerNo, TrainerName, TrainerDesc)
values
('T5690146', 'Mary Hoe', ...)
```